# Boost Fusion articles, examples, tutorials?

Tags: c++, templates, boost-fusion

Do you know any good resources/articles/examples of boost::fusion library usage?

Boost Fusion looks extremely interesting, I think I understand how it works and how to use the basics, but I'm looking for some resources that show any interesting usage/practices e.g. articles or blogs (apart from boost.org itself).

Comment: I have some example of boost fusion usage here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455904/print-information-in-test-mode-but-not-in-normal-execution/456184#456184 . Note that the code wasn't intended to be fast (another version made it really near to printf performance), but it's easy to optimize it.

Comment: Very good question, fusion is hard to understand for newbies like me. May be the good way to start with fusion is first to look at meta-programming introduction tutorials (without any MP lib). Hope that confirmed users will share here their precious knowledge about fusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought the comment by [johannes-schaub-litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) should be an answer, as I nearly overlooked it.

So here it is:
[Johannes' excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455904/print-information-in-test-mode-but-not-in-normal-execution/456184#456184).

There are also some [other examples in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-fusion). I particularly liked [the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157584/boostspiritqi-how-to-turn-inlined-parser-expressions-into-standalone-grammar).

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6V73Q7ULFi0

Brief intro to Fusion, but you might prefer it to docs.

Comment: I really like when he (Michael Caisse) explains things. I wanted to give link for slides https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2013/blob/master/thu/solving_world_problems_with_fusion.pdf?raw=true

Answer (score 2):

Seems like there aren't as many articles/posts about the usage (apart from the actual boost documentation of course).

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have found while trying to learn fusion :

- [the slides](https://github.com/boostcon/2009_presentations/raw/master/thu/fusion.pdf) of the boostcon 09 presentation of fusion by one of its authors
- [the slides](https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2013/blob/master/thu/solving_world_problems_with_fusion.pdf?raw=true) of the talk of Michael Caisse at boostcon 13 (NoSenseEtAl provided a link to the recording of the talk)