# Where can I find boost::fusion articles, examples, guides, tutorials?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

I am going to go ahead and shamelessly duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914399/boost-fusion-articles-examples-tutorials) because the accepted answer is essentially "nope, no guides" and it's been nearly a year now since it's been asked.  Does anyone know of any useful articles, guides, tutorials, etc. for boost::fusion besides the [barebones documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html) on boost.org? (which I'm sure is great as a reference after one has learned the library.)  I'm completely open to, say, a link to a book on Amazon.  Searched for it myself just now but all I came up with was green tea.  The top links on Google aren't much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ugh.  Still no bites... I did find some helpful examples in the `<boostdir>/libs/fusion/test` area though.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a shoddy answer, but the best documentation I've seen for Boost::Fusion is in the Boost::**Spirit** documentation, as sparse and unhelpful as it otherwise is.